# Retrieve data from the table when you have two tds

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

how can I **scrape** a website when I have something like that?
For example I have 2 tds for the title (header as well as for the value)
I want to export the data to a csv
For example this is the table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped product-page-specifications">
                        <tbody><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Product type</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">1</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Tip2</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">MMA
TIG/WIG
</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Material</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Metal </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Size</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Universal </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Color</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Black</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Content</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Material made of a material as resistant as possible</td>
                            </tr></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

And I want to export this to csv

```
Product type  Tip2 Material  Size      Color 
1             MMA  Metal     Universal  Black
```

I tried this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
table = soup.select_one("table")

output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('td'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

 df = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)
 print(df)
```

Comment: FYI “to scrap” means to throw away like rubbish. The correct term is __scrape__

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped product-page-specifications">
                        <tbody><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Product type</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">1</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Tip2</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">MMA
TIG/WIG
</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Material</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Metal </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Size</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Universal </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Color</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Black</td>
                            </tr><tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-4 text-muted">Content</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-8">Material made of a material as resistant as possible</td>
                            </tr></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser").find_all("td")

values = [h.getText(strip=True).replace("\n", " ") for h in soup[1::2]]
headers = [v.getText(strip=True) for v in soup[::2]]

pd.DataFrame([values[:-1]], columns=headers[:-1]).to_csv("your_table.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

```
Product type,Tip2,Material,Size,Color
1,MMA TIG/WIG,Metal,Universal,Black
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is that the designated "headers" are the first column of the table. So, you want to treat the following column(s) as the rows in your transposed output.

In this case I assume there can be a dynamic number of columns to become rows and so use [:nth-child ranges](http://nthmaster.com/) to dynamically loop from column 2 onwards, for however many columns there are. The first tr is added into the selector to correctly determine the actual column count per row. I also use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to pick out the first column to assign to df columns argument.

---

**csv:**

To stick with the lighter csv import rather than bringing in pandas

1. dynamic "row" count:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv

html = '''your html'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')  # html.parser
cols = [i.text for i in soup.select('.product-page-specifications td:nth-child(1)')]
num_rows = len(soup.select('.product-page-specifications tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(n+2)'))

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(cols)
    
    for col_num in range(num_rows):
        row = [i.text for i in soup.select(f'.product-page-specifications td:nth-child({col_num + 2})')] 
        w.writerow(row)
```

2. Only two rows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv

html = '''your html'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')  # html.parser

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow([i.text for i in soup.select('.product-page-specifications td:nth-child(1)')])  
    w.writerow([i.text for i in soup.select('.product-page-specifications td:nth-child(2)')])
```

---

**Pandas  (heavier import and not required here):**

1. dynamic "row" count:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

html = '''your html'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')  # html.parser  
cols = [i.text for i in soup.select('.product-page-specifications td:nth-child(1)')]
num_rows = len(soup.select('.product-page-specifications tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(n+2)'))

df =  pd.DataFrame([[i.text for i in soup.select(f'.product-page-specifications td:nth-child({col_num + 2})')] 
                     for col_num in range(num_rows)], columns = cols)
df.to_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', index= False)
```

If there will only ever be the two rows you can simply to:

2. 2 rows only:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame([[i.text for i in soup.select('.product-page-specifications td:nth-child(2)')]], columns = [i.text for i in soup.select(f'.product-page-specifications td:nth-child(1)')])
df
```